# Varchar PRIMARY_KEY cannot be longer than 191

Tags: mariadb, primary-key, varchar

I just tried to create the following table in a MariaDB using PHP7 with mysqli:

```
CREATE TABLE $tb_bad_log (
  ip varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  name varchar(255) default NULL,
  nr_tries int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  last_try varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  blocked enum('Y','N') NOT NULL default 'N',
  enter_user varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY (enter_user),
  KEY nr_tries (nr_tries),
  KEY blocked (blocked)
);
```

This gives me the error “Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes”, which persists if `enter_user` is 192 or more characters, but not if I restrict it to 191 characters or less. What is going on here?

(Yes, there is some strange stuff going on here. I'm trying to understand legacy code and get it to run.)

Comment: The collation is probably `utf8mb4` (4-byte unicode). `191 * 4 = 764`

Comment: There are 5 solutions here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes -- pick the one that fits best.

Answer (score 2):

Your database character set is most likely set to `utf8mb4` which means that every `char` will take up 4 bytes. `192` characters therefore requires `768` bytes of key space, making it too big. If you don't need `utf8mb4` on specific tables or columns, you can set the character set with the `CHARACTER SET` parameter at either the [table level](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/#table-level) or [the column level](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-character-sets-and-collations/#column-level).